# Was ending character reached or not

Tags: php, file, file-io

In summary I am using stream_get_line to read a line of a file, replace a string and then write the line to another file.

I am using stream_get_line and supplying the "ending" parameter to instruct the function to read lines, or if there is no new line then read 130 bytes.

What I would like to know is how can I know if the 3rd parameter (PHP_EOL) was found, as I need to write exactly the same line (except for my string replacement) to the new file.

For reference...

```
string stream_get_line ( resource $handle , int $length [, string $ending ] )
```

It's mainly needed for the last line, sometimes it will contain a newline character and sometimes it doesn't.

My initial idea is to seek to the last line of the file and search the line for a new line character to see if I need to attach a newline to my edited line or not.

Comment: What is an ending parameter?

Comment: Have edited my original question

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) if the stream is in ASCII mode (which only matters on Windows). That function will include the newline if it is found:

```
$line = fgets(STDIN, 131);
```

Otherwise, you could use [ftell](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php) to see how many bytes were read and thus determine whether there was a line ending. For example, if `foo.php` contains

```
<?php
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
    $pos = ftell(STDIN);
    $line = stream_get_line(STDIN, 74, "\n");
    $ended = (bool)(ftell(STDIN) - strlen($line) - $pos);
    echo ($ended ? "YES  " : "NO   ") . $line . "\n";
}
```

executing `echo -ne {1..100} '\n2nd to last line\nlast line' | php foo.php` will give this output:

```
NO   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
NO    29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 5
NO   3 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 
YES  78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 
YES  2nd to last line
NO   last line
```